# My wireless won't connect in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, newly installed on my Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: 12.04, dell, broadcom

I am a brand new user to Ubuntu (all of my previous experience being in Windows).  I have recently begun to dual boot for the sake of work, so I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1525.  It possesses a Broadcom BCM4312 Wireless card.  I have no troubles getting an ethernet connection to work, but my wireless is acting odd, to say the least.  I can see all available networks (obviously including my own), but whenever I try to connect to it, it repeatedly asks me to authenticate the connection.  I am absolutely positive that I am inserting the correct passphrase (WPA security setting), but it refuses to connect.  I have browsed and tried other responses to no avail, but I am completely new to Ubuntu and have no idea what some of the terminal commands are actually doing, so it could be user error.  Anyone out there willing to give me some help?  Thanks.

Edit: Terminal Responses

`lscpi -nn` response:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory 
Controller Hub [8086:2a00] (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 
Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [8086:2a02] (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated 
Graphics Controller (secondary) [8086:2a03] (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI 
Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI 
Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI 
Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio 
Controller [8086:284b] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 
[8086:283f] (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 
[8086:2841] (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 
[8086:2847] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI 
Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI 
Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI 
Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI 
Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] 
(rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface 
Controller [8086:2815] (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE 
Controller [8086:2850] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA 
Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2829] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller 
[8086:283e] (rev 02)
02:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller 
[1180:0832] (rev 05)
02:09.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host 
Adapter [1180:0822] (rev 22)
02:09.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter 
[1180:0592] (rev 12)
02:09.3 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller 
[1180:0852] (rev 12)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast 
Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 12)
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY 
[14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

`lsmod` response:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
michael_mic            12541  8 
arc4                   12474  4 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60238  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31778  1 
gpio_ich               13160  0 
joydev                 17394  0 
hid_generic            12485  0 
dell_wmi               12602  0 
sparse_keymap          13659  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            17210  0 
dcdbas                 14099  1 dell_laptop
coretemp               13362  0 
microcode              18396  0 
parport_pc             32115  0 
ppdev                  12850  0 
rfcomm                 38104  12 
bnep                   17791  2 
r852                   17906  0 
sm_common              16773  1 r852
snd_hda_intel          33029  3 
snd_hda_codec         116477  3 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13277  1 snd_hda_codec
usbhid                 46054  0 
hid                    82511  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uvcvideo               72249  0 
videobuf2_core         32212  1 uvcvideo
videodev              100265  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12757  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13213  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
r592                   17809  0 
memstick               15886  1 r592
snd_pcm                81124  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
psmouse                91022  0 
serio_raw              13032  0 
btusb                  17952  0 
bluetooth             189585  24 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
nand                   49703  2 r852,sm_common
nand_ids                8548  1 nand
mtd                    38671  2 sm_common,nand
nand_bch               13004  1 nand
bch                    21768  1 nand_bch
nand_ecc               13106  1 nand
lpc_ich                16993  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17276  0 
mac_hid                13078  0 
wl                   2906598  0 
snd_seq_midi           13133  0 
i915                  470823  3 
cfg80211              181041  1 wl
lib80211               14041  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
drm_kms_helper         47459  1 i915
snd_rawmidi            25426  1 snd_seq_midi
wmi                    18745  1 dell_wmi
drm                   240232  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_seq_midi_event     14476  1 snd_seq_midi
i2c_algo_bit           13317  1 i915
video                  19070  1 i915
snd_seq                51594  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28932  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14138  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62675  16 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14636  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14109  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17456  0 
parport                40931  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
firewire_ohci          36110  0 
firewire_core          61957  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12628  1 firewire_core
sdhci_pci              18263  0 
sdhci                  32293  1 sdhci_pci
sky2                   53629  0
```

Comment: Sure. I have a different Dell with the same wifi card, and it works relatively well. Can you add the outputs of `lspci -nn` and `lsmod` to the question. These commands simply print their outputs to the screen, nothing else.

Comment: Apparently it just magically began working?  I rebooted several times to no avail, then swapped over to Vista and played a round of League of Legends.  Rebooted in Ubuntu, and it's magically working again.  Just to make sure the problem is properly taken care of, I'll still post what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you start having more issues with it, you might try this command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

It worked for me on an older HP laptop.